# Increasing the size of a jQuery UI popup

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am working on a popup:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="OptionFormContainer" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false" data-overlay-theme="a">
       //CONTENT HERE
</div>
```

I am trying to increase the side of the popup but adding the following code does not effect it.

```
$('#OptionFormContainer').css({ "height": "5em", "width": "3em" });
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using jQuery dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery dialog:

```
$( "#OptionFormContainer" ).dialog({ width: 500 });
```

Have a look at http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-width